# << Operator throwing compile error

Tags: c++

I am following the basic libcurl curlcpp example below

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// RAII cleanup 
curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

// standard request object.
curlpp::Easy myRequest;

int main(int, char**)
{
    // Set the URL.
    myRequest.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(std::string("http://www.wikipedia.com")));

    // Send request and get a result.
    // By default the result goes to standard output.
    // Here I use a shortcut to get it in a string stream ...
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << myRequest.perform();

    std::string asAskedInQuestion = os.str();

    return 0;
}
```

It has been a while since I used c++ but I am sure I have used the << operator before. Am I missing an include needed to make it work?

Comment: According to http://www.animemanga-ita.net/francesco/curlplusplus_doc/classcurlpp_1_1easy.html `curlpp::easy::perform()` has return type `void`, i.e., nothing. `void` cannot be an argument of `ostream::operator <<`.

Comment: Please paste the relevant lines from error message.

Comment: Tobias is correct, its a shame when the examples provided with a library don't even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot redirect standard output like that: in order for the `<<` operator to work, the `myRequest.perform()` member function needs to return its output - either as a `string`, or as another object for which there exists an overload of the `<<` operator for output streams.

Since `myRequest.perform()` is void, you need to tell curlpp to write to your string stream by using some other mechanism. In curlpp that is done by setting a write stream option - like this:

```
std::ostringstream os;   // Here is your output stream
curlpp::options::WriteStream ws(&os);
myRequest.setOpt(ws);    // Give it to your request
myRequest.perform();     // This will output to os
```